# Loading a page correctly with Masonry + LessCSS

Tags: less, jsfiddle, jquery-masonry, masonry

I had a problem with the Masonry plugin causing to only function when the viewport is being changed, meaning the masonry boxes were invisible until you would resize the browser window. After that the boxes are not olny visible but also Masonry works as expected.

I resolved this problem by using regular CSS again for styling, and not [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org) anymore as I had intended.

But what would I be able to do to use both? (It doesn't seem like it's a simple 'reorder how the scripts are being loaded' kind of thing)

Funnily when I use jsFiddle and implement LESS CSS there, there is no problem. Maybe somebody can tell me what jsFiddle does to fix the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/rcygo5fy/

```
 code
```

Comment: jsfidfle not working. Please add the used libraries (with the right version).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rcygo5fy/9/

Comment: working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zo3ap6p5/. columnWidth option was wrong as well as the ordering of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Okay, now mine also works. I'lI had to track down the error first and then I had to rearrange the scripts by removing and re-pasting, hoping they would stack in the right order, testing which order would be agreeable with the processor. https://jsfiddle.net/rcygo5fy/9/ — so, back to the main problem... jsFiddle can do it. So what is the problem when I test the very exact code live and outside of jsFiddle?

Comment: if it's working on jsfiddle but not on your site, I would say that your code is the problem ;) To get deeper we would need to see your code.

Comment: here it is http://thomasmaier.me/jusch/

Comment: resize the browser window a bit

Comment: It's a timing issue. Masonry is called before the style is added to all elements.

Comment: jsfiddle does not use less.js. you could try to use the load event (https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of domready to be less.js agnostic. If this is not working you will need to listen to less.js `pageLoadFinished` event.

Comment: yeah but we added Less to jsFiddle and that does it. I think I don't have relevant understanding of javascript beyond pasting snippets. ... Wouldn't  I be able to do it exactly like jsFiddle with 
`$('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type','text/less');`
`less.env = 'development';`
`less.refreshStyles();` ...?

Comment: Have you tried to use the onload event? e.g. `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Comment: Syntax seems right. Last attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/rcygo5fy/12/. If it's not working I would assume to just drop less.js .. as it should not be used in production either way.

Comment: Why? isn't it specifically made to speed things up? I mean.. ususally... if it would be user-friendly...

Comment: Like Sass and Stylus CSS preprocessors are build to speed up the development and increase the maintainability, but you don't want to compile less to CSS on every request on production. You only compile it once and then cache it.

Answer (score 0):

"Solution": Since a solution would be a hassle with the code and compiling the CSS on every load is very heavy, especially client-side, the best solution is to leave LESS completely out of the end result and only use it for development but a LESS-to-CSS-rendered file for actual usage. With CSS the Masonry timing problem goes away.